# md-grid-list responsive attributes do not work upon resizing the browser window

Tags: angularjs-directive, material-design, angular-material, angular2-directives, angular-material2

I have md-grid-list which contains cards. I have set the number of columns to 4 in the grid-list. When I resize the browser window, the grid list will not resize according to the browser window and contents in the card gets overlapped and looks ugly. How do I set the grid-list to display dynamically according to the browser window size? Or How to set the number of cards in the grid according to the browser window size?

```
<md-grid-list cols="4" md-cols-sm="2" md-cols-md="4" md-cols-lg="8" md-cols-gt-lg="12"  rowHeight="250px" gutterSize="20px">
  <md-grid-tile  *ngFor="let data of myData">
      <md-card [style.background]="'lightBlue'" [style.minHeight]="'100%'" >    
    <md-card-title></md-card-title>
    <md-card-title></md-card-title>
    <md-card-content>
    <h2>    
    </h2>
    </md-card-content>  
    </md-card>
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

Comment: Are you using Angular 2 ?

Comment: @ShrutiAgarwal Yes. I am using Angular 2.4.10 version

Comment: The directives like md-cols-sm are not valid with it. Please have a look at this for more details : https://material.angular.io/components/component/grid-list

Comment: @ShrutiAgarwal Okay Thanks. If they are not valid, Which are the responsive directives to be used with grid in angular 2 for screen sizing?

Comment: I have mention the possible options in the answer below. Let me know if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 1):

The directives like md-cols-sm are not valid  for md-grid-list for your angular veresion. Please have a look at this for more details : [Angular 2 md-grid-list](http://material.angular.io/components/component/grid-list)

You can use flexbox layout by angular ([dzurico.com/angular-flex-layout](http://dzurico.com/angular-flex-layout) , [github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API](http://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API)) or write your own css class to implement the flexbox.

Comment: Thank you.I tried to install flex layout and i get this error message. Could you please help me ? I installed flex layout using "npm install @angular/flex-layout" . After installation, I get this typescript error message. "node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'." "node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InjectionToken'."

Comment: Did you get the error after installing flexbox? Can you please try installing flex layout again following steps in this link : https://alligator.io/angular/flex-layout/

Comment: I figured out that latest version of @angular/flex-layout will require Angular v4.x and will not be compatible with Angular v2.x  from this link https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: You can still import it  and use. I am using it with Angular 2.

Comment: Good to know it worked. You can accept it as answer to help others facing the same issue.